# Dirichlet Distribution - the underlying intuition.

Tags: statistics, intuition, multinomial-coefficients

I'm not a math expert, but I need dealing with some math tools for natural language processing research. One of the most common tools is the Dirichlet distribution. I know that with a multinomial distribution I can estimate the probability of a vector of outcomes to happen given a vector of *a priori* probabilities.

I've tried to understand the Dirichlet distribution comparing to the multinomial case, but I'm facing difficulties since most "tutorials" use too much formal jargon, which I don't have enough background knowledge to absorb. My guess is that Dirichlet distribution is a multinomial with more "vectors" of parameters, but I'm not sure if it's the real thing.

Hopefully someone will be capable of bringing a proper answer according to my level of expertise in statistics (if there is any). Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Dirichlet distribution is a *continuous* distribution, while the multinomial distribution is discrete. It's like the difference between the normal distribution and the binomial distribution: they have similar shapes, but in the latter the outcomes can only be integers while the former they are arbitrary real numbers. With Dirichlet vs. multinomial, your outcomes are *vectors* of real numbers rather than vectors of integers. By the way, Wikipedia has [an intuitive example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#String_cutting) of the Dirichlet distribution that I quite like.